# Grammar -Negative Imperative ( Weep not, Strive not.... or Don't weep)?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, imperative-sentences

I would like to know if those sentences are gramatical. I believe that is an old-fashioned way of saying "don't + base verb", but I'm not sure

> Strive *not*  to be a success but rather to be of value  (Einstein)
>
> Weep *not* for roads untraveled (Linkin park)

Is this correct or it should be written "Don't arrive, don't weep"?

Comment: Old-fashioned, noble but correct according to the rules of grammar.

Comment: _[Verb] not_ is archaic, but in the Einstein quote, _not_ could also be taken to refer to _to be a success_ (not X but Y).